# ASP.NET Timer only works in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer, scriptmanager

I am using the ajax timer control inside an update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>            
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The timer should update the label every second with the current datetime.

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Everything works fine in debug mode but when I run the site without debugger (CTRL+F5) or if I deploy the site to my server the timer does not tick.

But when I add "debug=true" to the web.config everything works fine. Even on my server.

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
```

Internet Explorer throws the exception "Object doesn't support this action" in ScriptResource.axd.

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT: I think I have solved it.**

I don't know why but two things can solve this issue:

- Using a ScriptManager instead of a ToolScriptManager
- Using the ToolScriptManager with CombineScripts="false"

I have no clue if this is a bug or not.

Maybe somebody can explain it.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in the latest AJAX Control Toolkit - I have just come across this error myself - It seems the only option is to downgrade to a previous version.

https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27639 and http://forums.asp.net/t/1962717.aspx?Timer+and+Script+Combining+w+ToolkitScriptManager

to fix the current issue i am having to run in debug mode until i can downgrade and test.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
Using the ToolScriptManager with CombineScripts="false"
```